# Bootstrap columns not aligning propery in Chrome (and they do in Firefox). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm trying to show two types of content in the same row. I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.

I'm dividing the row into two columns: the first one should have three card columns in wide monitors, and the rest should be occupied by the second column of content.

I started with:

```
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
  ...
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-9">
        <div class="card-columns">

              [this stuff is inside a php foreach() loop]
              <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">Título del artículo</div>       
              <div class="card-body">
              [content]
              </div>
              [end foreach]
        </div>
</div>
<div class="col col-3">
[content]
</div>
</div>

</main>
```

But firefox showed me the three columns of card-columns, and the last column at the bottom.

So I then tried:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
        <div class="card-columns">
[content]
        </div>
</div>
<div class="col col-3">
[content]
</div>
</div>
```

And now firefox shows me the expected result, but not Chrome.

I should add that I always have the same wrong result in Chrome.

I do attach a picture of what I mean.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: share html inside of `card-columns` class

Comment: did you add `container` before `row` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've just updated the question. Yes, I put everything inside a `container-fluid`. Inside the `card-columns` I just copied the example from the bootstrap documentation page, and inserted it with a foreach loop.